# using Custom Camera gets many issue with different android devices

Tags: java, android, camera

I am using custom camera on my Zenfone 2, Samsung Galaxy S3, Nexus 7 (2012) it worked (both Back camera and Front camera, even take picture and record video), no issue with it.

But when try with the other devices, like : Oppo, Sony Xperia M4, Samsung Galaxy S6. There are some issues :

- Oppo : get crash when open Camera in my application while default Camera of Oppo is OK.
- Sony xperia M4 & Samsung galaxy S6 : can not switch to Front camera. Even, it hangs for a while. However, default camera of both Sony and Samsung is OK.

The following codes is set for my application to use camera feature :

```
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CAMERA" />

<activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustPan"
        android:name = "ui.activity.camera.CustomCamera"
        android:configChanges = "orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation = "portrait" />
```

**CustomCamera.java** - Main class

```
public class CustomCamera extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * Single ton section
 */
public static singleton.Camera camera = singleton.Camera.getInstance();

/**
 * String section
 */
public static int current_orientation = 0;

/**
 * View section
 */
public static Camera mCamera;
public static Camera.CameraInfo mCameraInfo =
        new Camera.CameraInfo();

/**
 * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
 */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(int camera_id) {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(camera_id); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return c; // returns null if mCamera is unavailable
}

/** OnCreate method **/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_camera);

    // Should initialize new Camera after released
    mCamera = null;
    initialCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Should release camera before go to the other page
    // Because it need release for the other camera apps using camera,
    // If it not release, current app will not allow the other app use
    releaseCamera();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Should release camera before go to the other page
    // Because it need release for the other camera apps using camera,
    // If it not release, current app will not allow the other app use
    if (CameraPreviewFragment.IS_RECORDING_VIDEO) {
        CustomCamera.mCamera.stopPreview();

        // release camera
        releaseCamera();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Re-initialize if camera already released after resume from background
    if (mCamera == null) {
        // Initialize camera again
        initialCamera();
    }
}

/**
 * Initial methods
 */

private void initialCamera() {
    // Back Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance(0);

    // Set Camera Display Orientation
    CameraPreviewFragment.setCameraDisplayOrientation(
            this, define.Camera.CAMERA_BACK);

    // Get orientation listener
    new OrientationEventListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            getCurrentOrientation(orientation);
        }
    }.enable();
}

/**
 * Basic methods
 */

private int getCurrentOrientation(int orientation) {
    orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
    this.current_orientation = orientation % 360;

    return current_orientation;
}

public static void releaseCamera() {
    // Should release camera before go to the other page
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

**CameraPreview.java** - camera surface class

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the mCamera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        // Set the popular preview size & picture size
        // to apply for all android devices : Back camera only
        // If for Front camera, it will use default if not suitable
        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
            if (1600 <= size.width & size.width <= 1920) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Set parameters for camera
        try {
            CustomCamera.mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        }

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**CameraPreviewFragment.java** - Class to load preview of Custom Camera

```
 @Override

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_camera_preview, container, false);

    /**
     * Add Camera Preview into Layout
     */
    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), CustomCamera.mCamera);
    mFlCameraPreview.addView(mCameraPreview);

    return v;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ibtn_switch_back_or_front_camera:
            /**
             * Should reset camera for camera get new setting
             */

            // Switch between Front Camera & Back Camera
            current_camera_id = switchCurrentCameraID();

            refreshCameraPreview(getActivity(), current_camera_id);

            // Should remove view parent before add child
            Utils.removeViewParent(mCameraPreview);

            /**
             * Add Camera Preview into Layout
             */
            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), CustomCamera.mCamera);
            mFlCameraPreview.addView(mCameraPreview);
            break;
}
}

// for the Preview - from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)
// note, if orientation is locked to landscape this is only called when setting up the activity, and will always have the same orientation
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int camera_id) {
    CustomCamera.mCameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(camera_id, CustomCamera.mCameraInfo);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    if (CustomCamera.mCameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (CustomCamera.mCameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {
        result = (CustomCamera.mCameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    if (CustomCamera.mCamera != null)
        CustomCamera.mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

**activity_custom_camera.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/LinearLayout__Vertical_MatchParent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_custom_camera"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_camera_preview.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
style="@style/FrameLayout_"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_camera_preview"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

What I want is how my Custom camera in my application can work more correctly for popular Android devices, like Instagram, Camera 360 ...

The other thing, I did not use `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` This one will help me solve what's thing? It will reduce the supported Android device can download my application from Play store?

People who know,

Please help me,

Thank you,

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Can not solve. It depends on manufacturer

Comment: Did you solve specific manufacturers? What did Oppo, LG, Sony or HTC needed to support? Can you share some details?

Comment: Samsung, google, sony, lg ... Most of android devices.

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution for this. I am facing same issue in samsung device.

Comment: Please file a submit to Samsung Dev. (Samsung Community), might be it is `specifyDeviceIssue`